# How to pass argument for `\includegraphics[width=..]..` without causing "Runaway argument?"?

Tags: macros, optional-arguments, includegraphics

I'm going to despair: It seems nobody has a problem when passing an argument for the width of `\includegraphics`, but I always get `Runaway argument?`.
Whenever I remove the `[#2\textwidth]` from my command definition, the command works!

My command looks like this (still room to improve):

```
\newcommand{\figcap}[5][htbp]{%
\begin{figure}[#1]%
\centering%
\includegraphics[width=#2\textwidth]{#3}%
\caption{\label{\Lf{#5}}{\small{}#4}}%
\end{figure}
}
```

And my call is like this:

```
\figcap{1}{1920px-Cone-....png}{Normierte ... (blau, grün, rot).}{test}
```

Using `LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>` I get this error:

```
Runaway argument?
width=1\textwidth ]{1920px-Cone-....png}\caption {\label {\Lf \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \Gin@iii was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par
```

I've spend hours of reading and trying, but I don't find the problem.
The packages I'm using are:

```
documentclass[a4paper,draft,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{german}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{a4}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphics}
```

And before you ask: `\newcommand{\Lf}[1]{fig-#1}`

Comment: `\includegraphics[#2\textwidth]{#3}` is not valid syntax.  You need `\includegraphics[width=#2\textwidth]{#3}`.  It would help if you provided a complete working example for us to play with, rather than snippets.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes Sorry, you are right: That got lost during all my attempts to fix the command ;-) The whole document is quite long, sorry.

Comment: You are using the syntax of the **graphicx** package but have only loaded the **graphics** package (with s not x)

Comment: @Ulrich Diez: The first argument is optional; wouldn't LaTeX complain if the number of arguments were incorrect?

Comment: @David Carlisle: If you'd write that as answer, I could accept that as solution, because after changing "graphics" to "graphicx", the error is gone! Actually I had been using that syntax in a 20 year old document without using `graphix` (I was using ` epsfig` then). It seems `graphicx` is derived from `epsfig`, because it complains for my PNG file: `LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in 1920px-Cone-....svg.png (no BoundingBox).` Since when do PNGs have a BoundingBox?

Comment: @U.Windl as documented ifth eimage soze can not be found by any other method it tries reading it as an eps to find a bounding box comment (just in case...) but something is wrong if you get that for a png file, pdftex can read the size of png files natively.

Comment: @U.Windl actually (since 1993) epsfig is derived from graphicx, it is just a thin wrapper around graphicx supporting the syntax for documents that are 30 years old.